# MultiLine EditText in Android Material design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, androiddesignsupport

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_edit_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll4"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Description"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hint_grey" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I want to make the above **EditText** to have multi line. If the user press "enter" the cursor should get down to the second line.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add your EditText

```
<EditText 
...
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
/>
```

Answer (score 10):

you have to set

default lines in preview by `android:lines="5"`

limits of lines by `android:maxLines="10"`

start of typing by `android:gravity="start"`

try this code:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:hint="hint"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:lines="5"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000" />
```